# Prove that the summation from n=0 to infinity of a^n is 1/(1-a)

Tags: calculus, summation, infinity

Prove $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^{n} = \cfrac{1}{1-a}$$ for all a $\in$ $\textbf{R}$ where |a| $<$1 and describe what happens when |a|$\nless$ 1

- This is a calc two topic
- I have a start I just need help finishing it
  I started with the partial sums of this series. $s_n=1+a+a^2+a^{3}+...+a^n$
  I also looked at the partial sums of $as_n=a+a^2+a^3+...+a^n+a^{n+1}$
  Then I subtracted $s_n-as_n$ and this is where I got stuck

I eventually want to get to a point where I take the limit to prove this equality is true but I do not know how to proceed

Any help would be appreciated !! 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n = \frac{1}{1-a} 
$$
Let's see what the following leads to
$$
(1-a)\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n - \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^{n+1}\\  \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n - \sum_{k=1}^\infty a^k = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n - (\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n - 1) \\
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n - \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n - (-1) = 1
$$

so we have
$$
(1-a)\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n = 1 \implies \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n = \frac{1}{1-a}
$$

This approach does not really work when you have the divergent sum when $|a| > 1$ since we have a divergent sum multiplied by a constant does not yield another constant.

Comment: Everything is correct .. also continue please by answering what happens when $\vert a \vert \geq 1$ as requested by OP.

Comment: thank you so much! where did the k=1 a^k come from

Comment: @AhmadBazzi well that case is not really covered in the above expression since $a^n \to 0$ is broken.

Comment: I know but please clarify it to OP

Comment: @Parley it comes from $a\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^{n+1} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a^k$

Comment: @AhmadBazzi I see where you are coming from now ;)

Comment: gotcha ;) and here's a +1 for perfect explanation.

Comment: Oh so it was reindexed?

Comment: Thanks @AhmadBazzi.

Comment: @Parley yes it was a re-index. Which we can do for infinite sums.

Comment: This assumes that the series converges. You have to find the conditions when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n a^k = \frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a} $$

If $|a|<1$, then the sequence $a^{n+1} \to 0$. Therefore, the sequence of partial sums of $\sum a^n $ converges to $\frac{1}{1-a} $. In other words,

$$ \boxed{ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^n = \frac{1}{1-a} } $$

Comment: is this a proof by induction?

Comment: @Parley the first equation is using the expression of geometric series, which could be proved by induction indeed.